# What just Happen on Spyder

Tags: python, machine-learning, spyder, data-science

I was working on a data set of acme on python using spyder, as soon as i uses OneHotEncoder module on my independent variable which was a set of two variables(two columns), as soon as i execute the command my independent variable data disappear from Variable Explorer and the output on IPython console shows "<60x61 sparse matrix of type ''     with 120 stored elements in COOrdinate format>"

can anyone explain what happened here

Thanks

Comment: ... You created a sparse matrix? What do you mean " my independent variable which was a set of two variables(two columns)"? Are these columns in a data-frame? Or Python variables?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much for commenting , now i get it what was the problem.